How Many Levels / Trying To Figure out Bit Rate
I'm trying to figure out the following constellation, specifically the amplitude. I am trying to figure out the different levels (M) This particular QAM has 32 states (I get this), but I want to make sure I have this correct:
16 amplitude, so if I'm trying to get the number of bits, and with a baud rate of 9600:
9600 Symbols / second * log2(16) = 38400 bits / sec


Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify. -- If you have 32 states, why are you focusing on amplitudes? Wouldn't it be 9600 symbols / seconds * log2(32) bits / symbol = 48000 bits / second?

"log2(16)" Where has the 16 come from? You need log2(32) there.

There are not 16 different amplitudes in the constellation you provided.

The constellation diagram you provided represents a 32-QAM scheme, exactly 32 points in the constellation. It corresponds to 5 bits per symbol. $$ \log_2(32) = 5 \text{ bits/symbol} $$
With a baud rate of 9600 symbols/second, the data rate should be
$$9600 \, \text{symbols/second} \times 5 \, \text{bits/symbol} = 48,000 \, \text{bits/second}.$$
This means that the system can transmit data at 48000 bps using this 32-QAM constellation.

Thanks! I didn't quite understand the difference between the two. Thanks for pointing out this was a 32-QAM, that made a huge difference!

You have 32 symbols which is worth 5 bits per symbol.
With symbol rate of 9600 symbols per second, that is 48000 bits per second.
